# To edit JS and CSS right in the output

Tags: javascript

Here is an interesting trick how to see and edit your CSS and JS right in the output. For example, right in the output,  you can change the color from `red` to `blue`.

My question is why I cannot change, in the same way, the text that is printed by the script? I mean, regardless of any edits, the printed text is still `foo` and not e.g. `bar`. Is there a way to make it work?

```
<div></div>

<p>The contents of the <code>&lt;style&gt;</code> tag:</p>

<style contenteditable>
  div {
    color: red; /* You can change the color right in the **output**! */
  }

  script {
    background: lightgray;
  }

  style {
    background: aliceblue;
  }

  script, style {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<p>The contents of the <code>&lt;script&gt;</code> tag:</p>

<script contenteditable>
  function timer() {
    /* You cannot do the same trick to replace foo with bar... */
    document.querySelector('div').append('foo ');
  }

  setInterval(timer, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: That's freaking crazy .. maybe the problem with the script is that it is not recompiled by engine after such a change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `script` tag is executed only once when is inserted into DOM, then you  are only changing it's text content which does not reevaluate the `script`. You may emulate the script evaluation but then there is not much sense in the `script` tag here:

```html
<div></div>

<p>The contents of the <code>&lt;style&gt;</code> tag:</p>

<style contenteditable>
  div {
    color: red; /* You can change the color right in the **output**! */
  }

  script {
    background: lightgray;
  }

  style {
    background: aliceblue;
  }

  script, style {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<p>The contents of the <code>&lt;script&gt;</code> tag:</p>

<script id="code" contenteditable>
  document.querySelector('div').append('foo ');
</script>

<script>setInterval(() => eval(code.textContent), 1000)</script>
```